# Comparator in java 8

Tags: java, comparator

Recently I've updated Java to version 8, but I have problem with Comparator (in 7 version everything worked perfectly):

```
    lastplace = Collections.max(place,
                    new Comparator<Place>() {

                public int compare(Place o1,
                        Place o2) {
                    return (o1.getDateFrom()
                            .compareTo(o2.getDateFrom()));
                }
            });
```

Now Comparator needs to inherit other methods (thenComparingInt, thenComparingLong etc.), but I don't need them

How to solve this in few lines of code ?

Comment: So what is the problem? Have you at least tried to compile the code? I guess not, because if you had, you would have seen that the code compiled fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new mehods in Comparator class are default that you dont need to implement because it provides default implementation.I think the problem is with your IDE due to compiler compliance level set to 1.7.Just change the compiler level to 1.8 and if it not there upgrade your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

According to javadocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html those methods are marked as `default`, so You dont have to provide implementation. More info about default interface methods :http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/.

You can use lamda expression to simply implement Comparator interface. This might help : 
http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/java-8-lambda-tutorial/comparator-tutorial.php